# What is the background process when a tcl script is run?

Tags: tcl

When you start a tcl script, what is the background process that happens. ( similar to c compilation )?

When you start the expect, how the script process works?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a running Tcl interpreter and just `source` your script to run it (which avoids describing the whole interpreter startup sequence and initialization), the following things happen in any recent (8.x) Tcl interpreter.

This basically invokes some C-Code like `Tcl_EvalFile()` which loads the script into memory, and hands of the work of actually doing the execution to the internal `TclEvalEx()`, which is a private version of `Tcl_EvalEx()`, as documented here (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/Eval.htm).

This interprets the toplevel script without bytecode compilation, e.g. the script is parsed, once a command is found, it is executed directly. This is quite slow and the way the older Tcl 7.x operated all the time.

But if a command is executed, it is checked if the command can be byte-compiled into a more efficient form. This is the case for commands defined via `proc` so if a command gets executed the first time, the  `Tcl_EvalObjEx()` calls `TclCompileObj()` internally to get a bytecode representation of the command, which is cached inside the `Tcl_Obj` of the parsed command.

If the command cannot be compiled, it is executed directly, e.g. one of the functions in `generic/tclCmd*.c` is called, for example to handle the command `concat` the command would be `Tcl_ConcatObjCmd()` in `generic/tclCmdAH.c`. This function may also come from some C extension loaded into the interpreter and is treated exactly in the same way. The available commands are registered internally in some hash table, thats what `Tcl_CreateObjCmd()` does.

But if the command can be compiled, something different happens. In that case, the command is turned into a bytecode representation. For example for a trivial procedure like this: `proc c {a b} {concat $a $b}` this is turned into four bytecodes. You can actually inspect the generated bytecode via the `::tcl::unsupported::disassemble` command, have a look at this Tkcon session with a Tcl 8.6.3:

```
() 69 % proc c {a b} {concat $a $b}
() 70 % ::tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc c
ByteCode 0x00000000045A2660, refCt 1, epoch 16, interp 0x0000000002E26120 (epoch 16)
  Source "concat $a $b"
  Cmds 1, src 12, inst 10, litObjs 0, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x0000000002EB32A0, refCt 1, args 2, compiled locals 2
      slot 0, scalar, arg, "a"
      slot 1, scalar, arg, "b"
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-8, src 0-11
  Command 1: "concat $a $b"
    (0) loadScalar1 %v0     # var "a"
    (2) loadScalar1 %v1     # var "b"
    (4) concatStk 2 
    (9) done
```

This bytecode (the four lines at the bottom) is executed by a virtual machine inside the Tcl interpreter. It is a stack based VM currently. You can find its implementation inside the `generic/tclExecute.c` file.

Not all commands can be bytecoded yet, if a command has no matching bytecode, a call to the plain function is generated, e.g. one of the `Tcl_*ObjCmd` things mentioned for direct execution.

Bytecodes are much faster for most cases (nearly every time a command is reused). That is one reason for the advices to put all your code inside procedures (they get byte-compiled that way), and to brace your expressions.

Hope this illustrates the process a bit. I left out a few more complex details like compile epoches and the problems of co-routines, non-recursive engine etc.

Expect is identical to a normal Tcl for this, it just adds a few extra commands via `Tcl_CreateObjCmd()`.