# TCL proc and byte code compile - what is the link?

Tags: tcl

Several times I run into mentioning that it is best to put script into proc in order to boost run time performance, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672830/what-is-the-background-process-when-a-tcl-script-is-run) has the following:

> That is one reason for the advices to put all your code inside procedures (they get byte-compiled that way)

Something does not click in me.

Just as described in the answer, the first time a script runs, there is a check if a command can be byte-code compiled, if it is, then it is compiled. This makes total sense. But I do not see how "proc" plays an important role. E.g. compare the following 2 scripts:

```
set v [concat [lindex $::argv 1] [lindex $::argv 2]]
myCmd $v
```

and

```
proc p1 {v1 v2} {
  set v [concat $v1 $v2]
  return [myCmd $v]
}
p1 [lindex $::argv 1] [lindex $::argv 2]
```

My high level interpretation of the 2 scripts tells the following:

> 1. In running either script the first time, "set", "concat", "lindex" and "return" commands are compiled
> 2. The second script also has "proc" compiled.
> 3. "myCmd" is not compiled in either script
> 4. Subsequent running of either script runs the bycode except "myCmd".

So what is the advantage of "proc"?

I did run dissamble on the scripts:

The first script:

```
ByteCode 0x0x83fc70, refCt 1, epoch 3, interp 0x0x81d680 (epoch 3)
  Source "set v [concat [lindex $::argv 1] [lindex $::argv 2]]\nmy"
  Cmds 5, src 61, inst 50, litObjs 4, aux 0, stkDepth 4, code/src 0.00
  Commands 5:
      1: pc 0-41, src 0-51         2: pc 2-39, src 7-50
      3: pc 4-20, src 15-30        4: pc 21-37, src 34-49
      5: pc 42-48, src 53-60
  Command 1: "set v [concat [lindex $::argv 1] [lindex $::argv 2]]"
    (0) push1 0         # "v"
  Command 2: "concat [lindex $::argv 1] [lindex $::argv 2]"
    (2) push1 1         # "concat"
  Command 3: "lindex $::argv 1"
    (4) startCommand +17 1      # next cmd at pc 21
    (13) push1 2        # "::argv"
    (15) loadScalarStk
    (16) listIndexImm 1
  Command 4: "lindex $::argv 2"
    (21) startCommand +17 1     # next cmd at pc 38
    (30) push1 2        # "::argv"
    (32) loadScalarStk
    (33) listIndexImm 2
    (38) invokeStk1 3
    (40) storeScalarStk
    (41) pop
  Command 5: "myCmd $v"
    (42) push1 3        # "myCmd"
    (44) push1 0        # "v"
    (46) loadScalarStk
    (47) invokeStk1 2
    (49) done
```

The second script:

```
ByteCode 0x0xc06c80, refCt 1, epoch 3, interp 0x0xbe4680 (epoch 3)
  Source "proc p1 {v1 v2} {\n    set v [concat $v1 $v2]\n    return"
  Cmds 4, src 109, inst 50, litObjs 5, aux 0, stkDepth 4, code/src 0.00
  Commands 4:
      1: pc 0-10, src 0-67         2: pc 11-48, src 69-108
      3: pc 13-29, src 73-88       4: pc 30-46, src 92-107
  Command 1: "proc p1 {v1 v2} {\n    set v [concat $v1 $v2]\n    return"
    (0) push1 0         # "proc"
    (2) push1 1         # "p1"
    (4) push1 2         # "v1 v2"
    (6) push1 3         # "\n    set v [concat $v1 $v2]\n    return ["
    (8) invokeStk1 4
    (10) pop
  Command 2: "p1 [lindex $::argv 1] [lindex $::argv 2]"
    (11) push1 1        # "p1"
  Command 3: "lindex $::argv 1"
    (13) startCommand +17 1     # next cmd at pc 30
    (22) push1 4        # "::argv"
    (24) loadScalarStk
    (25) listIndexImm 1
  Command 4: "lindex $::argv 2"
    (30) startCommand +17 1     # next cmd at pc 47
    (39) push1 4        # "::argv"
    (41) loadScalarStk
    (42) listIndexImm 2
    (47) invokeStk1 3
    (49) done
```

So script 2 does have 1 less TCL command, but both scripts have 49 byte code commands.

Finally the running test, I comment out "myCmd" because I actually do not have such extension. Here is the result:

```
% time {source 1.tcl} 10000
242.8156 microseconds per iteration
% time {source 2.tcl} 10000
257.9389 microseconds per iteration
```

So the proc version is even slower.

What do I miss? Or rather, what is the exact understanding of proc and performance?

Comment: `concat` is often a fairly expensive operation, FWIW.

Answer (score 4):

The really big reason that putting things in a procedure matters is that procedures have a **local variable table**. Variables in the LVT can be accessed by numerical index, which is stupendously faster than the alternative (a lookup via a hash table, even though Tcl's got an *extremely* fast hash table implementation). It doesn't make much difference for a one-off call, but with repeated calls or a loop, the performance differences rapidly add up to something significant. This can quite easily make the extra cost of the extra compilation and stack frame management (procedures aren't free to enter, though we try to keep them cheap) basically irrelevant in real scripts.

And yes, Tcl actually bytecode-compiles everything. It's just that it often generates sub-optimal bytecode outside of procedure(-like context)s; in the limit case for suboptimality, all the bytecode is doing is assembling arguments into a list, doing a dynamic command invoke, and routing the result.

(It's important when reading Tcl's disassembled bytecode to remember that the costs of particular bytecodes are *not* all the same. You cannot just count the number of instructions to work out the cost in any useful way. For example, `push1` is very cheap but `invokeStk1` is potentially very costly. Another example, `loadScalarStk` is usually much more expensive than `loadScalar1`; the latter is used inside procedures only.)

Comment: Also, @Leon's answer is a good illustration of why this stuff matters.

Answer (score 3):

The following two scripts demonstrate the performance gain due to usage of `proc`s. In the second script the internal loop is extracted into a `proc`, leading to a 5x speedup.

**without_proc.tcl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set sum 0
set n 10000
set k 100
for { set i 0 } { $i < $k } { incr i } {
    set s 0
    for { set j 0 } { $j < $n } { incr j } {
        set s [expr {$s + $j}]
    }
    set sum [expr {$sum + $s}]
}
puts "sum=$sum"
```

---

**with_proc.tcl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc foo {n} {
    set s 0
    for { set j 0 } { $j < $n } { incr j } {
        set s [expr {$s + $j}]
    }
    return $s
}

set sum 0
set n 10000
set k 100
for { set i 0 } { $i < $k } { incr i } {
    set s [foo $n]
    set sum [expr {$sum + $s}]
}
puts "sum=$sum"
```

---

**Benchmark:**

```
$ tclsh
% time {source with_proc.tcl} 1
sum=4999500000
67482 microseconds per iteration
% time {source without_proc.tcl} 1
sum=4999500000
406557 microseconds per iteration
```

or

```
$ time tclsh with_proc.tcl 
sum=4999500000

real    0m0.089s
user    0m0.080s
sys     0m0.004s

$ time tclsh without_proc.tcl
sum=4999500000

real    0m0.401s
user    0m0.388s
sys     0m0.016s
```